'Button' does not contain a definition for 'onClick'
GameObject newButton = Instantiate(_buttonPrefab, _parentPrefab);

Button buttonOnClick = newButton.GetComponent<Button>();
buttonOnClick.onClick.AddListener(Testttttssad);

For some reason, Visual Studio/Unity keep trying to use a different class of Button, and I get an error:

Assets\Scripts\DialogSystem\DialogueManager.cs(52,31): error CS1061: 'Button' does not contain a definition for 'onClick' and no accessible extension method 'onClick' accepting a first argument of type 'Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


For some reason, Visual Studio/Unity keep trying to use a different class of Button well then that is the main issue ... tell it explicitly which one you want to refer to (UnityEngine.UI.Button probably)

You need to point the compiler to the correct Button class explicitly.
Instead of:
Button buttonOnClick = newButton.GetComponent<Button>();

use this:
UnityEngine.UI.Button buttonOnClick = newButton.GetComponent<Button>();

Alternatively, you could add a using directive to the top of the class:
using Button = UnityEngine.UI.Button;


You also need to use the correct type in the GetComponent call.
